# How to test Ansible playbook using Docker

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm new to ansible (and docker). I would like to test my ansible playbook before using it on any staging/production servers.

Since I don't have access to an empty remote server, I thought the easiest way to test would be to use Docker container and then just run my playbook with the Docker container as the host.

I have a basic DockerFile that creates a standard ubuntu container. How would I configure the ansible hosts in order to run it against the docker container? Also, I suspect I would need to "run" the docker container to allow ansible to connect to it.

Comment: Molecule is the official testing framework: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/testing-your-ansible-roles-molecule

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Running the playbook in a docker container may not actually be the best approach unless your stage and production servers are also Docker containers. The Docker ubuntu image is stripped down and will have some differences from a full installation. A better option might be to run the playbook in an Ubuntu VM that matches your staging and production installations.

That said, in order to run the ansible playbook within the container you should write a Dockerfile that runs your playbook. Here's a sample Dockerfile:

```
 # Start with the ubuntu image
 FROM ubuntu
 # Update apt cache
 RUN apt-get -y update
 # Install ansible dependencies
 RUN apt-get install -y python-yaml python-jinja2 git
 # Clone ansible repo (could also add the ansible PPA and do an apt-get install instead)
 RUN git clone http://github.com/ansible/ansible.git /tmp/ansible

 # Set variables for ansible
 WORKDIR /tmp/ansible
 ENV PATH /tmp/ansible/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
 ENV ANSIBLE_LIBRARY /tmp/ansible/library
 ENV PYTHONPATH /tmp/ansible/lib:$PYTHON_PATH

 # add playbooks to the image. This might be a git repo instead
 ADD playbooks/ /etc/ansible/
 ADD inventory /etc/ansible/hosts
 WORKDIR /etc/ansible

 # Run ansible using the site.yml playbook 
 RUN ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/site.yml -c local
```

The ansible inventory file would look like

```
[local]
localhost
```

Then you can just `docker build .` (where `.` is the root of the directory where your playbooks and Dockerfile live), then `docker run` on the resulting image.

Michael DeHaan, the CTO of Ansible, has an informative [blog post on this topic](http://www.ansible.com/blog/2014/02/12/installing-and-building-docker-with-ansible).

Comment: Thank you. So basically you deploy "locally" from within the docker container, rather than the container being the "host". I didn't think of that. I'll give it a run through tomorrow evening to see how it fits into my use case. Also thank you for the heads up that it may not be the best approach! Will take that into consideration.

Comment: @Andre Did you get some results out of it?

Answer (score 16):

There's a working example regarding this: https://github.com/William-Yeh/docker-ansible

First, choose the base image you'd like to begin with from the following list:

- `williamyeh/ansible:debian8-onbuild`
- `williamyeh/ansible:debian7-onbuild`
- `williamyeh/ansible:ubuntu14.04-onbuild`
- `williamyeh/ansible:ubuntu12.04-onbuild`
- `williamyeh/ansible:centos7-onbuild`
- `williamyeh/ansible:centos6-onbuild`

Second, put the following `Dockerfile` along with your playbook directory:

```
FROM williamyeh/ansible:ubuntu14.04-onbuild

# ==> Specify playbook filename;   default = "playbook.yml"
#ENV PLAYBOOK   playbook.yml

# ==> Specify inventory filename;  default = "/etc/ansible/hosts"
#ENV INVENTORY  inventory.ini

# ==> Executing Ansible...
RUN ansible-playbook-wrapper
```

Third, `docker build .`

For more advanced usage, the role in Ansible Galaxy [`williamyeh/nginx`](https://github.com/William-Yeh/ansible-nginx) also demonstrates how to do a simple integration test for a variety of Linux distributions on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/)’s Ubuntu 12.04 worker instances.

Disclosure: I am the author of the `docker-ansible` and `wiliamyeh/nginx` projects.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from provisioning localhost (the machine where you have Ansible installed), you can also tell Ansible to:

1. create a new docker container,
2. provision that container,
3. destroy that container.

For this to work you need such a `hosts.yaml` file:

```
all:
  hosts:
    mycontainer:
      ansible_connection: docker
    localhost:
      ansible_connection: local
```

such a `playbook.yaml` file:

```
---
- name: Create a container to be provisioned later
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: create docker container
      docker_container:
        name: mycontainer
        image: python:2.7.16-slim-stretch
        command: ["sleep", "1d"]

- name: Provision the container created above
  hosts: mycontainer
  roles:
    - simple
```

and another playbook file: `destroy.yaml` used to destroy the container:

```
---
- name: Destroy a container
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: destroy docker container
      docker_container:
        name: mycontainer
        state: absent
```

Create also a simple role: `roles/simple/taksks/main.yaml`

```
---
- name: Create a file
  copy:
    content: "hi!!"
    dest: /tmp/hello
    force: yes
    mode: 0555
```

And now to create a container and provision it, run:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./hosts.yaml ./playbook.yml
```

Verify that container was provisioned (the file was created):

```
docker exec mycontainer cat /tmp/hello
```

To destroy the container run:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./hosts.yaml ./destroy.yml
```

There are of course disadvantages:

- the container must have python installed
- some Ansible modules might not work, because additional python packages have to be installed. E.g. if you wanted to deploy docker containers (in the docker container), you have to install docker python SDK (`pip3 install docker`)

I was inspired by this blog post: https://medium.com/@andreilhicas/provision-docker-containers-with-ansible-30cc5ee6d950

Answer (score 4):

I've created a role for this vary scenario: https://github.com/chrismeyersfsu/provision_docker. Easily start Docker containers and use them in your role or playbook, as inventory, to test.

Includes:

- Curated Dockerfile for Ubuntu 12.04 & 14.04 as well as CentOS 6 & 7 that put back in the distro-removed init systems
- start ssh

Also note the examples all have a `.travis.yml` file to form a CI pipeline using Travis CI.

**Examples:**

- Simple: https://github.com/chrismeyersfsu/provision_docker/tree/master/test
- Simple: https://github.com/chrismeyersfsu/role-iptables/tree/master/test
- Advanced: https://github.com/chrismeyersfsu/role-install_mongod/tree/master/test